# Creating shapefile from text file using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, fields-attributes, cursor, insert

Fourth update, per suggestions from comments and professor. Still getting the "takes no arguments" error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Pythonpro\pythonProject2\anothercreateschools.py", line 19, in 
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts, ["SHAPE@", "ID",  "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "NAME", "ADDRESS", "ZIP", "DISTRICT"]) as cursor:
TypeError: InsertCursor() takes no arguments"

updated script

```
import arcpy
import fileinput
import os
wrkspce = "C:/lab11/pt2"
arcpy.env.workspace = wrkspce
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
schpts = "schools.shp"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(102649)
sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(wrkspce, schpts, "Point", spatial_reference=sr)
infi = os.path.join(wrkspce, "schools.txt")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"ID")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"LONGITUDE", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"LATITUDE", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"NAME","TEXT",field_length = 50)
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"ADDRESS","TEXT",field_length = 50)
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"ZIP","TEXT",field_length = 10)
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"DISTRICT")
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts, ["SHAPE@", "ID",  "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "NAME", "ADDRESS", "ZIP", "DISTRICT"]) as cursor:
    for line in fileinput.input(infi):
        if "ID" in line:
            continue
        else:
            mysplit = line.split(",")
            ID = (mysplit[0])
            XCoordinate = (mysplit[1])
            YCoordinate = (mysplit[2])
            NAME = (mysplit[3])
            ADDRESS = (mysplit[4])
            ZIP = (mysplit[5])
            DISTRICT = (mysplit[6])
            point = arcpy.Point(XCoordinate, YCoordinate)
            pointgeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, sr2)
            newRow = (pointgeom, ID, XCoordinate, YCoordinate, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP, DISTRICT)  # the number and order of values must match fields in the list you specify in the cursor
            cursor.insertRow(newRow)
```

Third update per my professors edits, Throwing
"TypeError: InsertCursor() takes no arguments"

```
import arcpy
import fileinput
import os
wrkspce = "C:/lab11/pt2"
arcpy.env.workspace = wrkspce
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
schpts = "schools.shp"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(102649)
sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(wrkspce,schpts,spatial_reference=sr)
infi = os.path.join(wrkspce, "schools.txt")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"ID")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"NAME","TEXT",field_length = 50)
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"ADDRESS","TEXT",field_length = 50)
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"ZIP","TEXT",field_length = 10)
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"DISTRICT")
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts,["ID","SHAPE@","LONGITUDE","LATITUDE","NAME","ADDRESS","ZIP","DISTRICT"])
with cursor:
    for line in fileinput.input(infi):
        mysplit = line.split(",")
        ID = float(mysplit[0])
        XCoordinate = float(mysplit[1])
        YCoordinate = float(mysplit[2])
        NAME = float(mysplit[3])
        ADDRESS = float(mysplit[4])
        ZIP = float(mysplit[5])
        DISTRICT = float(mysplit[6])
        point = arcpy.Point(XCoordinate, YCoordinate)
        pointgeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, sr2)
        newRow = (pointgeom, ID,XCoordinate,YCoordinate,NAME,ZIP,DISTRICT)
        cursor.insertRow(newRow)
    del cursor
```

Here is my updated script per suggestions, I am still pretty lost.

```
import arcpy, fileinput
wrkspce = "C:/lab11/pt2"
arcpy.env.workspace = wrkspce
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
schpts = "schools.shp"
txt = "C:/lab11/pt2/schools.txt"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(102649)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(wrkspce,schpts,spatial_reference=sr)
#sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984") # GCS_WGS_1984, factory code 4326
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts, ["SHAPE@"]) # creates an insert cursor
for line in fileinput.input(txt): # open the file
    if 'ID' in line: # if the line is the file header
        continue # do nothing and continue to next iteration
    else: # if the line is a data line
        point = arcpy.Point() # creates a point object
        ID, point.X, point.Y,NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP, DISTRICT = line.split(",") # sets point coordinates
        pointgeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, sr) # makes a PointGeometry
        cursor.insertRow([pointgeom]) # inserts a new row. note a row is a list [ ]
        arcpy.management.AddField(schpts, ID, "SHORT")
        arcpy.management.AddField(schpts, NAME, "TEXT", field_length=50)
        arcpy.managment.AddField(schpts, ADDRESS, "TEXT", field_length=50)
        arcpy.managment.AddField(schpts, ZIP, "TEXT", field_length=10)
        arcpy.management.AddField(schpts, DISTRICT, "SHORT")
# close the GPS file and perform clean up
fileinput.close()
del point
del pointgeom
del cursor
```

I am working on a lab right now and very lost on how to move forward. we need to create a shapefile from the following text file

```
ID,LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,DISTRICT
1,-111.585741,35.225927,Christensen Elementary School,4000 N. Cummings St,86004,9
2,-111.522826,35.269495,Cromer Elementary School,7150 E Silver Saddle Rd,86004,8 
.....
```

Two things our professor wanted us to consider. I think I managed the first but not the second.

> When you create a blank shapefile, make sure it is assigned the
> spatial reference of NAD 1983 SPCS for AZ Central Zone FIPS 0202. b.
> When you create a point geometry for a school, make sure it is
> assigned the spatial reference of WGS 1984.
>
> The output shapefile must have all the attributes shown in the text
> file. Note that when you create a blank shapefile using the
> `arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass()` tool, the  output shapefile
> only has three fields: FID, Shape, and Id. You will store the school
> IDs in the Id field. But you must use the
> `arcpy.management.AddField()` tool to add the following additional
> fields into the new shapefile after creating it:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far. I do not know what more I can do.

```
import arcpy
import fileinput

import os
wrkspce = "C:/lab11/pt2"
arcpy.env.workspace = wrkspce
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
schpts = "schools.shp"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(102649)
#sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference(4356)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(wrkspce,schpts,spatial_reference=sr)
infi = os.path.join(wrkspce, "schools.txt")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"ID","SHORT")
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"NAME","TEXT",field_length = 50)
arcpy.managment.AddField(schpts,"ADDRESS","TEXT",field_length = 50)
arcpy.managment.AddField(schpts,"ZIP","TEXT",field_length = 10)
arcpy.management.AddField(schpts,"DISTRICT","SHORT")


cursor= arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts,["ID","LONGITUDE","LATITUDE","NAME","ADDRESS","ZIP","DISTRICT"])
#cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts,"shape@XY")
for line in fileinput.input(infi):
    mysplit = line.split(",")
    ID = float(mysplit[0])
    XCoordinate = float(mysplit[1])
    YCoordinate = float(mysplit[2])
    NAME = float(mysplit[3])
    ADDRESS = float(mysplit[4])
    ZIP = float(mysplit[5])
    DISTRICT = float(mysplit[6])
    newRow = (ID,XCoordinate,YCoordinate,NAME,ZIP,DISTRICT)
    cursor.insertRow(newRow)
```

I know I am probably adding too many fields and some could be the ones that are in the shape file, but I do not know how to rename them and fill them in properly per the instructions.

Comment: You have too many code blocks here. It's extremely difficult to see what you are trying to do, much less formulate an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, good start.

You have point coordinates in EPSG:4326 (WGS84).  You need to create a [`Point`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/point.htm) object from the X (LONGITUDE) and Y (LATITUDE) fields, add the `Point` and the appropriate [`SpatialReference`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm) to a [`PointGeometry`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm) object, then [insert that geometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) using the appropriate `shape` token (plus the other fields). Hint - it's not `shape@xy` (look for "geometry" in the list of `shape` tokens).

For bonus points, you could also specify an appropriate [datum transformation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listtransformations.htm) to transform from WGS84 to NAD83.

Re. your [first update](https://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/446065/3),

1. `# sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference(4356)` should uncommented and the correct code is `4326` not `4356`, e.g.  `sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)`.
2. You are trying to add fields inside the loop. Don't. Add the fields straight after you create the featureclass, *then* loop.
3. In your updated `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` you haven't included any of the required fields e.g `["SHAPE@","NAME","ADDRESS","ZIP","DISTRICT"]`
4. You've assigned the wrong spatial reference to the `PointGeometry` it's WGS84 (i.e. `sr2`)
5. You forgot to `insertRow`

Re. your 2nd update - `with cursor:` is wrong. Instead use:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts,["SHAPE@", "ID","LONGITUDE","LATITUDE","NAME","ADDRESS","ZIP","DISTRICT"])
for line in fileinput.input(infi):
    etc...
```

Note I reversed ID and shape@ above because you used that order in this line:

```
newRow = (pointgeom,ID,XCoordinate,YCoordinate,NAME,ZIP,DISTRICT)
```

Comment: As this is a school work question, I can't provide the code. You need to figure it out, but I will edit my answer shortly to address some issues in your update.

Comment: my professor sent me an update as well. But I keep throwing an "InsertCursor() takes no arguments, I have no idea how to rectify other than that my code is cleaner. now I can post that update as well

Comment: my professor sent another update, similar to yours, yet I am still getting this error no matter what. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Pythonpro\pythonProject2\anothercreateschools.py", line 19, in <module>
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(schpts, ["SHAPE@", "ID",  "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "NAME", "ADDRESS", "ZIP", "DISTRICT"]) as cursor:
TypeError: InsertCursor() takes no arguments

Comment: thanks again for your help. I think this is close but it still is failing, I can't find much info about the error that is being thrown

Comment: Try it without the `with` (the [doc examples](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) don't use `with`)